# Multiple project using static ref log.cs class (using log4net ) to create one log file?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I knew this question has been asked many times but my scenario is bit different. I have multiple projects in my solution. I have a static Log class which i reference statically (add as link) to different projects inside my solution. I would like to use one single log file for all the project logging. How can i achieve this ? 
My example Log File :

```
public static class Log
{
    private static ILog _log;

    public static void Initialize(Level logLevel, string logFile, string loggerName = null)
    {
        if (loggerName == null)
            loggerName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        // root config
        var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.Level = logLevel;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();

        // Get logger with given name
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
        // Add appender to log
        var fileAppender = CreateFileAppender(logFile);
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(fileAppender);
    }

    public static void d(string o, Exception e = null)
    {
        _log.Debug(o, e);
    }

    public static void e(string o, Exception e = null)
    {
       _log.Error(o, e);
    }

    public static void i(string o, Exception e = null)
    {
        _log.Info(o, e);
    }

    public static void w(string o, Exception e = null)
    {
        _log.Warn(o, e);
    }

    private static IAppender CreateFileAppender(string logFileName)
    {
        var appender = new FileAppender
        {
            Name = "FileAppender",
            File = logFileName,
            AppendToFile = true,
        };

        var layout = new PatternLayout
        {
            ConversionPattern = "%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} [%level] [%appdomain] [%thread] [%logger] - %message%newline%exception"
        };

        layout.ActivateOptions();
        appender.Layout = layout;
        appender.ActivateOptions();
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
        return appender;
    }
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is use the same file name in each project that uses this class.

Comment: What happens when there is simultaneous writing ?

Comment: If you have different processes writing to the file, set the appender's `LockingModel` to `InterProcessLock`, or if you only have different threads writing simultaneously, use `MinimalLock` instead -- see the [log4net faq](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#single-file) for more info.

Comment: Thanks ! my case, different processes writing to the same file. Also The first Project (which initialize first time) is writing the log and the other process which started later does not writing the log to the file ? What could be the reason ? Also when i stopped my first process, then the second process start to write to the log ?

Comment: Because [the default locking model keeps a lock on the file until it is closed](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.ExclusiveLock.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @stuartd ! Just using the same file name in each project solves the problem (also take care of locking model) but it also introduced another problem. "The first Project say A (which initialize Log.cs first time) is writing the log and the other process (say B, C etc) which started later does not writing the log to the file"

The actual Log.cs was present in Project B and I statically referenced the Log.cs in Project A. Now, I moved (physically) the Log.cs class from Project B to Project A and for all other projects i statically referenced the new file. Then the every project started to write the log in same file !